# Find all integer coordinates in a given radius

Tags: performance, algorithm, geometry, coordinates

Given a two-dimensional coordinate system how can I find all points with integer coordinates in a radius from a given point? I want the points as x-coordinate and y-coordinate value.

Finding points in a square around the given point is easy and could be done like that:

```
for(int x = -radius + point.x; x < radius + point.x; ++x)
for(int y = -radius + point.y; y < radius + point.y; ++y)
{
    points.insert(point(x, y));
}
```

But how can I find the points in a circle around the given point? This algorithm is performance related but not accuracy related. So it doesn't matter if a point closes to the radius than 1 is added or not. In other words, I do not need floating point accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. English is not my first language. I updated the question text and title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simplest solution: take a square and filter it:

```
Point point(100, 100);
for(int x = -radius; x <= radius; ++x)
for(int y = -radius; y <= radius; ++y)
if(x*x + y*y <= radius* radius)   {
    points.insert(Point(x + point.x, y + point.y));
}
```

Comment: Also this method creates a spoke at each of the 4 outer points: http://i.imgur.com/wirxfJP.jpg

Comment: @PsychoDad: the same as it meant in the question. Also, those spikes are correct behaviour.

Comment: Note that if `point.x` or `point.y` are not integer then the code needs some adjustment.

Answer (score 5):

One way is an outer loop on x from -R to +R and an inner loop on y according to the y values of the circle at that x value (from -sqrt(r^2 - x^2) to sqrt(r^2 - x^2) if the center is at 0,0), if the center is at X,Y - simply add X or Y to all loop ranges in the same manner as you did in your example

Answer (score 2):

You can make a small modification to the midpoint circle algorithm to get a filled circle.

First generate the coordinates:

```
data = new int[radius];
int f = 1 - radius, ddF_x = 1;
int ddF_y = -2 * radius;
int x = 0, y = radius;
while (x < y)
{
    if (f >= 0)
    {
        y--;
        ddF_y += 2; f += ddF_y;
    }
    x++;
    ddF_x += 2; f += ddF_x;
    data[radius - y] = x; data[radius - x] = y;
}
```

Then visit all the interior points:

```
int x0 = center.X;
int y0 = center.Y - Radius;
int y1 = center.Y + Radius - 1;

for (int y = 0; y < data.Length; y++)
{
    for (int x = -data[y]; x < data[y]; x++)
    {
        doSomething(x + x0, y + y0);
        doSomething(x + x0, y1 - y);
    }
}
```

That saves some work visiting points that won't be in the circle, but at the expense of a little pre-processing. It definitely won't help for smaller circles, and for bigger ones, well, I honestly don't know. You'd have to benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code just parses the boundary along a quarter circle to determine the inner area. It does not need to compute the distance for the outer points, nor for the inner points. (*edit*: but finally, all points of the filled circle are added)

In some mini-Java-benchmarks, for small radius (<10), it is of the same speed as the simple approach with parsing the full square. For radius 20-40 it is about 2 times faster, and it achieves a speedup of about 4 times for radius > 50. For some much larger radius (>200) the speedup decreases again, since for any approach the dominating time is then needed for creating and adding the >100k points - regardless of how they are determined.

```
// add the full length vertical center line once
for (int y = -radius + point.y; y <= radius + point.y; ++y)
    points.insert(Point(point.x, y));

int sqRadius = radius * radius;

// add the shorter vertical lines to the left and to the right
int h = radius;
for (int dx = 1; dx <= radius; ++dx) {
    // decrease h
    while (dx*dx + h*h > sqRadius && h > 0)
        h--;

    for (int y = -h + point.y; y <= h + point.y; ++y) {
        points.insert(Point(point.x + dx, y));
        points.insert(Point(point.x - dx, y));
    }
}
```

Comment: The circle *is* filled - but it does not determine the distance to inner points, similar to the midpoint algorithm by harold.

Comment: Then I will definitely try that out.

Comment: Is there a reason why you add the full length vertical center line first? Why not merge it into the later loops?