# Java - Loop through all pixels in a 2D circle with center x,y and radius?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a `BufferedImage` that I want to loop through. I want to loop through all pixels inside a circle with radius `radius` which has a center x and y at `x`,`y`.

I do not want to loop through it in a square fashion. **It would also be nice if I could do this and cut O complexity in the process, but this is not needed. Since area of a circle is `pi * r^2` and square would be `4 * r^2` that would mean I could get `4 / pi` better O complexity if I looped in a perfect circle.** If the circle at `x`,`y` with a radius of `radius` would happen to be larger than the dimensions of the `BufferedImage`, then prevent going out of bounds (this can be done with an if statement I believe to prevent going out of bounds at each check).

Examples: `O` means a recorded pixel while `X` means it was not looped over.

Radius 1

```
X   O   X
O   O   O
X   O   X
```

Radius 2

```
X   X   O   X   X
X   O   O   O   X
O   O   O   O   O
X   O   O   O   X
X   X   O   X   X
```

I think the proper way to do this is with trigonometric functions but I can't quite get it in my head. I know one easy part is that all Pixels up, left, right, and down in `radius` from the origin are added. Would like some advice incase anyone has any.

```
private LinkedList<Integer> getPixelColorsInCircle(final int x, final int y, final int radius)
{
    final BufferedImage img; // Obtained somewhere else in the program via function call.
    final LinkedList<Integer> ll = new Linkedlist<>();

    for (...)
        for (...)
        {
            int x = ...;
            int y = ...;

            ll.add(img.getRGB(x, y));   // Add the pixel    
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the second answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285358/find-all-integer-coordinates-in-a-given-radius might be helpful.

Comment: You should repeat the basics about Big-O notation. Circle areas grow quadratically, therefore, the pixels to cover are in O(n^2). The important thing about Big-O is that it predicts problems for really huge amounts of data, since a linear growth means that half a second becomes two seconds with more data while exponential growth means that half a second becomes a week. As for your case, the difference in pixels between the circle and the square will only matter if the part of the program is within it's deepest depth, called a thousand times per second. In your case, I would totally go with

Comment: the method over the square, simply because it is more readable than other methods. In most cases, readability > shaving off nanoseconds.

Comment: `LinkedList`s are horrible for performance if all you use them for is to insert elements at the end (and later iterate them).

Comment: @Tucuxi I disagree. LinkedLists have `O(1)` insertion and have the same iteration as every other data structure (`O(n)`). Arrays won't work because I don't know the size of what I will be dealing with. `ArrayList` will be bad as it will have to expand as I add more elements. What better Data Structure would you suggest?

Comment: `LinkedList`s have horrible memory locality and a 2-pointer overhead, while `ArrayList`s do not. This more than makes up for having to expand ArrayLists once in a while. ArrayLists are ~10x slower; notice that ~10 is a constant, and Big-O disregards constants - so they both belong to the same complexity class, despite there being very few cases where LinkedList makes sense (large elements, lots of insertions and removals not at the end-of-list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the center of the circle `O(x,y)` and the radius `r` the following coordinates `(j,i)` will cover the circle.

```
for (int i = y-r; i < y+r; i++) {
    for (int j = x; (j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2 <= r^2; j--) {
        //in the circle
    }
    for (int j = x+1; (j-x)*(j-x) + (i-y)*(i-y) <= r*r; j++) {
        //in the circle
    }
}
```

Description of the approach:

1. Go from the top to the bottom perpendicularly through the line which goes through the circle center.
2. Move horizontally till you reach the coordinate outside the circle, so you only hit two pixels which are outside of the circle in each row.
3. Move till the lowest row.

As it's only the approximation of a circle, prepare for it might look like a square for small `r`s

Ah, and in terms of Big-O, making 4 times less operations doesn't change complexity.

## `Big-O =/= complexity`

Comment: When you say Big-O does not mean complexity, do you mean by, the fact that as `n` increases to infinity, the operations you do become insignificant in the scope of the whole algorithm? Much like how, if you had `O(1/2 n)`, you would drop the `1/2` and just have `O(n)`?

Comment: I'm saying according to other answers, that they are not exactly the same. BigO is just a tool to describe complexity but as most of the tools, it has some weaknesses.

Comment: @tucuxi yea, corrected - Answering questions tagged [tag:algorithm] I don't care that much about language.

Comment: So it looks like this method hurts complexity even more so than looping through a square grid? Proof of that is the fact that we are increasing `x` and `y` by one and checking on every pixel. The same is done if we were working with a square. By that logic, both are equal. But then, this operation uses a check on every pixel involving multiple multiplications (repeated adding for the processor). I wonder, is there any way to improve this?

Comment: Nope. By this logic we're only going through pixels which are inside circle and those that are first outside the circle. You can try to modify the condition to loop through the circle only.

This code is optimal. As the area of the circle is O(r^2), you have to perform O(r^2) changes.

you can only fight with the constant which has some influence. That's what I did.

instead of r^2 operations

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I was looking at a lot of different variations and got yours confused with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285358/find-all-integer-coordinates-in-a-given-radius). Thanks a lot!

Comment: If `x+r, x+0` is in the circle, then `x+0, y+r` should be in the circle too. I suggest `i <= y+r`.

Answer (score 3):

While xentero's answer works, I wanted to check its actual performance (`inCircle1`) against the algorithm that OP thinks is too complex (`inCircle2`):

```
public static ArrayList<Point> inCircle1(Point c, int r) {
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(r*r); // pre-allocate
    int r2 = r*r;
    // iterate through all x-coordinates
    for (int i = c.y-r; i <= c.y+r; i++) {
        // test upper half of circle, stopping when top reached
        for (int j = c.x; (j-c.x)*(j-c.x) + (i-c.y)*(i-c.y) <= r2; j--) {
            points.add(new Point(j, i));
        }
        // test bottom half of circle, stopping when bottom reached
        for (int j = c.x+1; (j-c.x)*(j-c.x) + (i-c.y)*(i-c.y) <= r2; j++) {
            points.add(new Point(j, i));
        }
    }
    return points;
}

public static ArrayList<Point> inCircle2(Point c, int r) {
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(r*r); // pre-allocate
    int r2 = r*r;
    // iterate through all x-coordinates
    for (int i = c.y-r; i <= c.y+r; i++) {
        int di2 = (i-c.y)*(i-c.y);
        // iterate through all y-coordinates
        for (int j = c.x-r; j <= c.x+r; j++) {
            // test if in-circle
            if ((j-c.x)*(j-c.x) + di2 <= r2) {
                points.add(new Point(j, i));
            }
        }
    }
    return points;
}

public static <R extends Collection> R timing(Supplier<R> operation) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    R result  = operation.get();
    System.out.printf("%d points found in %dns\n", result.size(),
            TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toNanos(System.nanoTime() - start));
    return result;
}

public static void testCircles(int r, int x, int y) {
    Point center = new Point(x, y);
    ArrayList<Point> in1 = timing(() -> inCircle1(center, r));
    ArrayList<Point> in2 = timing(() -> inCircle2(center, r));
    HashSet<Point> all = new HashSet<>(in1);
    assert(all.size() == in1.size()); // no duplicates
    assert(in1.size() == in2.size()); // both are same size
    all.removeAll(in2);
    assert(all.isEmpty());            // both are equal
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    for (int i=100; i<200; i++) {
        int x = i/2, y = i+1;
        System.out.println("r = " + i + " c = [" + x + ", " + y + "]");
        testCircles(i, x, y);
    }
}
```

While this is by no means a precise benchmark (not much warm-up, machine doing other things, not smoothing outliers via n-fold repetition), the results on my machine are as follows:

```
[snip]
119433 points found in 785873ns
119433 points found in 609290ns
r = 196 c = [98, 197]
120649 points found in 612985ns
120649 points found in 584814ns
r = 197 c = [98, 198]
121905 points found in 619738ns
121905 points found in 572035ns
r = 198 c = [99, 199]
123121 points found in 664703ns
123121 points found in 778216ns
r = 199 c = [99, 200]
124381 points found in 617287ns
124381 points found in 572154ns
```

That is, there is no significant difference between both, and the "complex" one is often faster. My explanation is that integer operations are really, really fast - and examining a few extra points on the corners of a square that do *not* fall into the circle is really fast, compared to the cost of processing all those points that *do* fall into the circle (= the expensive part is calling `points.add`, and it is called the exact same number of times in both variants).

In the words of [Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth):

> programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in
>   the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming

Then again, if you really need an optimal way of iterating the points of a circle, may I suggest using [Bresenham's Circle Drawing Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#C_Example), which can provide all points of a circumference with minimal operations. It will again be premature optimization if you are actually going do anything with the O(n^2) points inside the circle, though.

Comment: Thanks for this. With that in mind, I guess it comes down to readability which the square method takes but the uniqueness of the other method (where it goes downwards, increases left until it hits the distance of the radius, then goes back to the center and increases rightwards is really interesting. Downside is also three for loops vs two.

Comment: Readability is best, in my opinion. Everybody understands "look at everything in square, take the points that are inside". For an extreme case of optimal-but-hard-to-read, follow the Bresenham link.  You should only optimize stuff which is really worth it - see the Knuth quote.

Comment: @xenteros no. Asymptotic notation discards constants; so for constant k, `BigTheta(k*n^2)` is the same thing (equivalence class of functions) as `BigTheta(n^2)`. Also, you have to choose the right n. Both algorithms look at exactly the same number of pixels (= the ones in the circle)  - and that's the slow part. The pixels outside the circle but in the square are, measurably, not that big of a deal.