# Fast Integer Coordinates Inside/along a Circle Centered at origin with radius r

Tags: algorithm, performance, geometry

Consider that you have a circle centered at 0,0 with radius r.

I'd like to get all the integer points available that are inside this circle. This problem is easy to solve.

One may just iterate over a square from `x = -r to +r` and `y =-r to +r` and see `if x * x + y * y <= r * r`, if so, add the point to your result.

However, what's the quickest way to do this? I feel there should be some type of hack that we can take the calculations from `(2r)^2` to `4/3 r^2`

More particularly, I have a feeling that we can calculate the length of the inscribed square, then add the outer remaining components. I'm unsure of how to do this though. The math is a little dense. I'm refraining from posting code because I'd like a general algorithm response, but if one has preference, he may state the final benchmark that this will be used in should use a JVM language.

Any help?

Note: this is similar to the gauss's circle problem, but instead of counting the number of points, I want to know what the points are.

Comment: I'd like to note I am aware of this question, but was wondering if we could do better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285358/find-all-integer-coordinates-in-a-given-radius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the values directly by computing the maximum y (the second coordinate of the point on the circle at the vertical of (x,0)) for each value of x like that:

```
for x in [-floor(r), floor(r)]
    y_max = floor(sqrt(r^2 - x^2))    # Pythagora's theorem
    for y in [-y_max, y_max]
        # (x, y) is good !
```

I don't think you can do much better (maybe you can compute y_max faster but that won't be a big win) because anyway you have these points in the result.

**EDIT**:

This is in Pi*r^2 time, which is the least you can do since it's the number of points.
You can maybe save a few computations by doing only a quarter circle and getting the other ones by symmetry, but I'm not even sure it's faster, and it's certainly longer to write.