# decay function for heatmap in ggplot2

Tags: r, spatial

have a mostly math question with a spatial component. I have a 2D top-down map of a synthetic task environment for a psychology experiment which I have represented currently in a spreadsheet.  There are locations in this environment that we want to present to participants using a heatmap, adding some ambiguity about the specific point of interest using some decay function. What's a simple way to create a dataframe or matrix that starts with something like this (`5` is the location of interest):

```
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,5,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
```

and turns it into something like this which I can pass to ggplot2 geom_bin2d() or similar?

```
1,1,1,1,1,0
1,3,3,3,1,0
1,3,5,3,1,0
1,3,3,3,1,0
1,1,1,1,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
```

As a follow-on, are there simple ways I can procedurally jitter/offset to create a pattern that isn't exactly over the 'true' location?

```
0,1,1,1,1,1
0,1,3,3,3,1
0,1,3,5,3,1
0,1,3,3,3,1
0,1,1,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learned how to create the decay kernel I asked about above. The example function below generates a circular kernel, but if you want a square one all you need to do is comment out the `dplyr::filter(radius_from_center...` call below.

You will first need to get your matrix into paired vectors or a dataframe with `x_pts` and `y_pts`. Since I was pulling data in from a 2D map using [tidyxl](https://github.com/nacnudus/tidyxl#:%7E:text=tidyxl%20imports%20non-tabular%20data%20from%20Excel%20files%20into,and%20%E2%80%98.xlsm%E2%80%99%20via%20the%20embedded%20RapidXML%20C%2B%2B%20library.) this step was done for me already. Special thanks also to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285358/find-all-integer-coordinates-in-a-given-radius) post for providing the solution in principle for cutting out the circular pattern.

```
    get_circle_kernel <- function(
    x_pts = 0,
    y_pts = 0,
    radius = 5L,
    jitter = 5L){
   if(is.null(x_pts)|is.null(y_pts)){
    stop("Specify a dataframe with `row` and `col` variables.")
  }

  # sample the row and column jitter
  x_jitter <- sample(-jitter:jitter, size = 1)
  y_jitter <- sample(-jitter:jitter, size = 1)

  # update col_pts and row_pts so they reflect jitter
  x_pts <- x_pts + x_jitter
  y_pts <- row_pts + row_jitter

  # draw a filled circle of points with alpha for each [row_pts, col_pts]
  df_circle <-
    tibble::tibble(
    sheet = sheet_pts,
    y = (y_pts - radius):(y_pts + radius),
    x = (x_pts - radius):(x_pts + radius),
    character = character_pts,
    bgColor = bgColor_pts,
    alpha = alpha_pts
  ) %>%
    # df %>%
    tidyr::expand(x, y, tidyr::nesting(sheet, character, bgColor)
                  ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(radius_from_center = sqrt((x - x_pts) ^ 2 + (y - y_pts) ^
                                              2)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(radius_from_center <= radius) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(alpha = (max(radius_from_center) - radius_from_center) / max(radius_from_center))

  return(df_circle)
  }
```